# System architecture design in .Net Application

Tags: entity-framework, design-patterns, model-view-controller, ado.net, asp.net-web-api2

Please find below architecture diagram, which one of my client has proposed for a project. Project is quite big size and currently its using SOA with ADO.Net(Stored procedures) for database operations.

[image]

I am little reluctant to use messaging service, as it will add extra layer and may create additional perfomance issues.

Please give your inputs on my below queries

(1) Main issue we are facing with current architecture
 - when a long running stopred procedure is running it slows down other operations as well. That is why we have separated one big database into multiple databases.
 - As application logic is quite complex currently we have stored procedure which have complex queries.

(1) would it be possible to use EF and replace ADO.Net completely. How to replace stored procudures having complex(or big) queries involving around 20 tables.

(2) How to maintain transections when we have multiple databases, I think this would be very difficult.

(3) If possible would you please suggest me some sample or application using similar architecutre, so that I can create a pilot application and test it with my current database.

---

Instead I would prefer below architecture , which is kind of micro service architecture where each application writes data to its database using Generic repository and EF and when applications wants to talk to each other( i.e. to insert/update/fetch data) , then it will use messaging service. Please let me know which approach is better.

[image]

Comment: If performance is your key criteria, EF may not be the right choice. [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) might be a good compromise.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the Messaging Service has actually solved a lot of the issues that you are seeing in 1) with long running procedures.

I have used `ActiveMQ` and `RabbitMQ` as a messaging service in previous large projects.

In one scenario, I was able to remove blocking by using the messaging service.  So instead of calling the stored procedure, the Business Logic dumped the job into a queue that could be processed later.

In another scenario, I was able to improve on this again by splitting the Business Logic into identical workers.  The Jobs were distributed to each of the workers in a Round-Robin Fashion using the Messaging Service.  It was effectively an implementation of the `Competing Consumers Pattern`.  The following gives a good explanation:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html

Answer (score 0):

> Project is quite big size and currently its using SOA

The keyword here is quite big. Big applications tend to get messy (tightly coupled) after a while and therefore separation is of importance.

How you would do it depends on what your team know and are comfortable with.

In my experience building applications based on messaging and CQRS tends to hold ground over the years as you physically separate the business domains and the API is much more fine-grained than messaging service contracts.

imho it's a mistake to expose the business layer to the MVC applications as it makes it easy to tightly couple them. Instead invoke the services from them.

Services has bad reputation mostly because people forget that they should have a good design too. Don't let them grow or be GOD classes that can do everything. Keep them small and well defined. I prefer services that defines business actions instead of CRUD actions, especially if you want to protect the business layer and have better consistency in the data store.